# Solr 4.0 is Holding Reference to Deleted Files

Tags: java, solr, lucene

We have configured a Solr server which we feed with data extracted from a database and we configured it as master. This master provides data to a few other slaves using replication mechanism configured as follows:

```
  <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
      <lst name="master">
          <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
          <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
          <str name="commitReserveDuration">00:00:10</str>
      </lst>
      <str name="maxNumberOfBackups">1</str>
  </requestHandler>
```

The strange thing is that the java process running this solr instance is holding reference to deleted files. If a `lsof` is done I can see:

```
java      17564 solr_master   44r      REG              253,2 4229809586     705005 /var/solr_master/data/index/_aegu.fdt (deleted)
java      17564 solr_master   45r      REG              253,2 4229809586     705005 /var/solr_master/data/index/_aegu.fdt (deleted)
java      17564 solr_master   49r      REG              253,2   17686596     705138 /var/solr_master/data/index/_ahjh.fdt (deleted)
java      17564 solr_master   51r      REG              253,2 4229809586     705005 /var/solr_master/data/index/_aegu.fdt (deleted)
```

The index is updated constantly, and slaves check for replication every 20 secods.

The commit is not done explicitly, it is using auto-commit configured as follows:

```
  <autoCommit> 
    <maxTime>15000</maxTime> 
    <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
  </autoCommit>
```

Does anyone sees what am I doing wrong, or does somebody faced the same problem, and on this case, what was the solution?

I'm using `LUCENE_40`, could this be related somehow to some bug in Lucene?

I already took a look at [the Solr bug list](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/solr), but I didn't find anything. An upgrade would be something not that easy in the current structure, I hope it is just a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide twice as much free space on your volume as the current size of the indexes for the merge operations. Do the reference number to deleted files increase over the time?(if not just increase the ulimit and let the gc do the rest), otherwise check the `netstat`for "CLOSE_WAIT" connections to replica nodes.

Comment: +1 that was a good guess, but already did it, and there is no connection opened to solr itself, and just as reference the file descriptors are stable when looked at solr manager, but if I take a look into the system they are increasing

Comment: just a hunch but can you say <openSearcher>true</openSearcher> and see if it has the same behavior? also if you disable replication. 
I would go for softCommit in order to avoid the risk of a leak if it's possible.

Comment: you were right, there was a few connections opened, I took a look on the wrong server when wrote the message above. thanks for your help! No OpenSearch configuration was changed..

Comment: Worst case for a merge can use 3X the size of the index, but 2X is good enough for normal operation.